# MoonMail setup/required variables

Tags: moonmail

I'm trying to setup MoonMail using their guide on the project GitHub which mentions

> Add variables to `s-variables-<stage>-<region>`:

But not what variables are even required? Trying to set the one variable mentioned (`apiHost`) and doing a `sls resources deploy` causes a failure.

Anyone actually managed to set this project up on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

These variables should suffice:

```
apiHost
defaultRegion
clicksRCU
clicksReportRCU
clicksReportWCU
clicksWCU
defaultRCU
defaultWCU
opensRCU
opensReportRCU
opensReportWCU
opensWCU
recipientsRCU
recipientsWCU
scheduledAtIndexRCU
scheduledAtIndexWCU
scheduledCampaignsRCU
scheduledCampaignsWCU
sentEmailsRCU
sentEmailsWCU
defaultApiKey
defaultApiSecret
defaultEmailAddress
defaultFromName
stage
iotEndpoint
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any doco of what those variables map to at all?

Comment: Not really, but everything ending with RCU or WCU are used to assign the number of read and write capacity units to dynamodb tables. Besides of that, you get defaults for email sending (api keys, email address, etc.) or  `apiHost`, which is used for links parsing and redirect